# ROS: Can we get a list of nodes started by launchfile

Tags: c++, xml, ros

I have different launchfile that launch different nodes.
I would like to display the launched nodes in a UI.

I can get the running nodes with no problem but theres one corner case where that wont display all the nodes in the launch file: if the node crashed after it has started.

when you launch the launch file via roslaunch, you can see a list of nodes

```
started roslaunch server http://vm:40549/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.15.14

NODES
  /
    GNSS (gnss_dummy/gnss_dummy_node)
    IMU (imu_dummy/imu_dummy_node)
    Video_recorder (video_recorder/video_recorder_node)
```

is there anyway to retrieve that list ?

```
[Video_recorder-9] process has finished cleanly
```

or can we retrieve the terminated nodes ?

Comment: Does [rosmon](https://github.com/xqms/rosmon) helps in anyway?

Comment: I assume the corner case you mention should not happen and if it happens, maybe the best is to kill all the others nodes by using the required tag in roslaunch. Another possibilty is to use the respawn tag for all nodes

Comment: Rosmon is very interesting !!
Yes Rafael this is how i will have to do it if i cannot retrieve terminated nodes or the list of nodes launched from the launchfile.
could aslo do a xml reader, but thats what roslaunch is already doing.

Answer (score 2):

Use options

```
--nodes <package-name> <launch-file>
```

or simply

```
--nodes <launch-file>
```

to retrieve the nodes of the launch file.

e.g.:

```
roslaunch --nodes roslaunch $ROS_ROOT/tools/roslaunch/example.launch
```

or

```
roslaunch --nodes roslaunch example.launch
```

See:

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools

Comment: my mistake i haven't specify that i want to retrieve that list in the program written in c++.
Theres a method in the ROS framework that returns the running node which is not perfect in my case but like rafael rey mentioned, if the node is not running, maybe the robot shoudnt be running...
But in my case, I would like to display it in the user interface.
So the only solution is to parse the xml and make the list and compare with the running ones to see which one are alive or not.
I haven't implemented it yet... I cannot offer the code